# Nodejs Pagination

Tags: node.js, mongodb, frontend, pug

I want to make a pagination with Nodejs and Mongoose. I can limit the posts but I couldn't handle the connection of front-end to back-end.

**this is app.js:**

```
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  var perPage = 2
  var page = req.params.page || 1

  Metin
  .find({})
  .skip((perPage * page) - perPage)
  .limit(perPage)
  .exec(function(err, metins) {
      Metin.count().exec(function(err, count) {
          if (err) return next(err)
          res.render('index', {
              metins: metins,
              current: page,
              pages: Math.ceil(count / perPage)
          })
      })
  })
});
```

**And this is my index.pug**

```
extends layout

block content
  body
    br 
    br
    br
    .container
      ul.list-group
        each metin, i in metins
          li.list-group-item
            a(href="/metin/" + metin._id)= metin.baslik
```

I want to add buttons that can pass to related paginated webpage. Can you please help me?

Something like below this line can be solution ?

```
a(href='?page=' + pages)= length.pages.
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`while`](https://pugjs.org/language/iteration.html#while) iterator to loop over the `pages` variable to make a number for each of your pages. And conditionally show/hide Previous/Next links based on `current` variable. This should work if you don't have a large amount of pages:

```
ul
  if current > 1
    li
      a(href=`?page=${parseInt(current) - 1}`) Previous
  - var i = 1
  while i <= pages
    li
      a(href=`?page=${i}`)= i++
  if current < pages
    li
      a(href=`?page=${parseInt(current) + 1}`) Next
```

Additionally, see [this](https://www.makeschool.com/academy/track/standalone/pete-s-pet-emporium---advanced-web-recipes/pagination) example.

Comment: Kardeşim Türkçe biliyor musun ?

Comment: Your code works fine but in my app.js I have a problem that when I cange page other articles are not shown. Why that it could be happen?

Comment: `app.get('/', function (req, res) {` should be `app.get('/', function (req, res, next) {`