# Pagination in mongoose and handlebars using node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I don't know how to paginate my posts in mongoose and how to also implement it in front end. I'm using handlebars template. My model name is Post. Please I need your helps

Comment: Okey I will wait a minute

Comment: What have you tried already?

Answer (score 0):

Okey firstly we come to our app.js. In mongoose documentation you can find these .limit() and other values in internet. Just google it.

```
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  var perPage = 5
  var page = req.query.page

  Post
  .find({})
  .skip((perPage * page) - perPage)
  .limit(perPage)
  .exec(function(err, posts) {
      Post.count().exec(function(err, count) {
          if (err) return next(err)
          res.render('index', {
              current: page,
              pages: Math.ceil(count / perPage),
              posts: posts,
          })
      })
  })
});
```

index.pug:

```
extends layout

    block content
      body
        br 
        br
        br
        .container
          ul.list-group
            each post, i in posts
              li.list-group-item
                a(href="/posts/" + posts._id)= posts.title
    ul
      if current > 1
        li
          a(href=`?page=${parseInt(current) - 1}`) Previous
      - var i = 1
      while i <= pages
        li
          a(href=`?page=${i}`)= i++
      if current < pages
        li
          a(href=`?page=${parseInt(current) + 1}`) Next
```

References

https://www.makeschool.com/academy/track/standalone/pete-s-pet-emporium---advanced-web-recipes/pagination

[Nodejs Pagination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61838202/nodejs-pagination)

https://evdokimovm.github.io/javascript/nodejs/mongodb/pagination/expressjs/ejs/bootstrap/2017/08/20/create-pagination-with-nodejs-mongodb-express-and-ejs-step-by-step-from-scratch.html

https://mongoosejs.com/docs/2.7.x/docs/finding-documents.html

What we have done is: firstly we set perpage and page. Perpage means the posts that will be shown in your one page. Page is you know just normal website page.

Then we find(). Posts and limit them and by skip we skip the old ones**(I am not sure about that)**.

After that we set current page and pages. And in pug(index) we set them with pug and javascript.

Comment: But am using handlebars as my template

Comment: The main idea is important. The you can convert it

Comment: You are just trying to get solution. But you dont get information.

Comment: Also I dont know handlebars template

Comment: I'm finding it difficult to implement the current page and previous page to handlebars

Comment: I'm now getting the pages but I don't know how I can implement the previous and next pages but others are working good

Comment: I will try to convert it wait me

Comment: Yes it uses html

Comment: But you just want to solution without learning. I would not help you in a long term

Comment: I dont know handlebars sorry :(

Comment: But I will try it wait a minute

Comment: I have implemented others and they are working fine. But the previous and next button are not working

Comment: You can ask another question to convert it. Bu if this answer is usefull can you please tick on that post.